# Java printjob is not printing anything after creating Jar and exe created with Launch4j

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, itext, print-job-control

Java printjob is working in eclipse but when we convert the application into exe everything works proper except PrintJob. Can anyone support me?
Note: Using Windows 7

```
public static void print() {

        PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument();
        pdf.loadFromFile("C:\\Mayura\\KFF Titrator Report.pdf");

        PrinterJob loPrinterJob = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        PageFormat loPageFormat  = loPrinterJob.defaultPage();
        Paper loPaper = loPageFormat.getPaper();

        //remove the default printing margins
        loPaper.setImageableArea(0,0,loPageFormat.getWidth(),loPageFormat.getHeight());

        loPageFormat.setPaper(loPaper);
        loPrinterJob.setPrintable(pdf,loPageFormat);

        //display the print dialog
        if (loPrinterJob.printDialog()) {
            try {
                loPrinterJob.print();
            } catch (PrinterException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please, post a minimal code sample of your problem so we can have a starting point to help you.

Comment: Are you sure no exception occurs?